# OGR set different features to column name in PDF

Tags: python, ogr, ogr2ogr, gdal-translate, vrt

I'm trying to import shapefile data into a geospatial PDF using OGR and Python.

My shapefiles are structured as follow: `shapefile1.shp: {stratt1: string1, intatt1: 1, ...}` and `shapefile2.shp: {stratt2: string2, intatt2: 2, ...}`

[image: Shapefile1 and Shapefile2]

From the documentation and other answers in SO I found the `OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=name` command, but it only works for one shapefile. Thus, if I import several shapefiles at once, I get only `feature1, feature2, feature3` and so on at the feature tree, as it can be seen in the following image:

[image]

This is odd, because with `OGR_DISPLAY_LAYER_NAMES=names` I'm able to change the layer name of several shapefiles at once like `OGR_DISPLAY_LAYER_NAMES=  "points1, points2"`, but I had no luck finding a way to do the same for the features. Any ideas?

Because I'm doing it with Python, my code looks like this:

```
co = ["OGR_DATASOURCE=" + vrt, "OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=" + "sat1, sat2"]
gdal.Translate(outpath, imagery, format="PDF", outputSRS="EPSG:4326", creationOptions=co)
```

(Again, the part failing is the `"OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=" + "sat1, sat2"` one)

My VRT file (called vrt above):

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="points1">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">shapefile1.shp</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSQL>SELECT stratt1 AS sat1, intatt1 as inat1 FROM shapefile1</SrcSQL>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="points2">
        <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="1">shapefile2.shp</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSQL>SELECT stratt2 AS sat2, intatt2 as inat2 FROM shapefile2</SrcSQL>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Any ideas how could I achieve my goal with only one `gdal.Translate()` call?

**TLDR:**

In the screenshot of the PDF you can see that every feature in `points1` is displayed as `string1`, the attribute from the column `stratt1` in `shapefile1`. This is correct.

In the screenshot of the PDF you also can see that every feature in `points2` is displayed as `feature1, feature2, feature3...` and so on. This is NOT correct. It should be called `string2` following the same principle as above.

I can´t do `"OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=" + "sat1, sat2"` because `OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=name` doesn´t take lists, nor it is possible to call it two times in the `creationOptions` of `gdal.Translate()`

**Edit to @cm1's answer**

[image]

Comment: If you are most interested in the end result it should be enough to edit the  OGRVRTLayer names in the VRT file.

Comment: Right, I can use `<OGRVRTLayer name="shapefile1"` in the VRT file instead of `OGR_DISPLAY_LAYER_NAMES = shapefile1` in the `creationOptions` of `gdal.Translate`. This doesn´t solve the main problem though, as in the PDF tree the attributes keep appearing as `feature1, feature2` and so on. For one shapefile I could use `OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=strattribute1` and it would work perfectly, but if I have more than one in my VRT file I can´t figure out how to get the attribute names right

Comment: You seem to have in data `strattribute_1` but in code you use `strattribute1`. Is that typo in your question? And when you have done `SELECT *, strattribute_1 AS at1` you have a layer with name "at1". Check the layer names with `ogrinfo my.vrt`. I wonder if the tutorial that is referred in http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html is still valid but if could be worth a look.

Comment: That was a typo in my question. I edited my question overall, I hope it´s more understandable now. The layer in `SELECT *, strattribute_1 AS at1`, after the edit now `SELECT stratt1 AS sat1`, is used in `"OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=" + "sat1"` and works properly. But I just can´t figure out how to do the same for `"OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=" + "sat2"` at the same time

Comment: Try to add double quotes like this: `co = ["OGR_DATASOURCE=" + vrtFixed, "OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=" + "\"strattribute_1, strattribute_2\"", "OGR_DISPLAY_LAYER_NAMES=" + "\"streets, points\""]`

Comment: after your editing, try like that: `co = ["OGR_DATASOURCE=" + vrt, "OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD=" + "\"sat1, sat2\""]`

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I tried it, sadly both `points1` and `points2` now are back to `feature1, feature2, feature3...` and so on :(

Comment: In command line,  `OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD` and `OGR_DISPLAY_LAYER_NAMES` require double quote, like `OGR_DISPLAY_LAYER_NAMES="streets, points"`. Maybe problem is about them (\")

Comment: For sure it requires quotes if you cut the string with a space. `OGR_DISPLAY_LAYER_NAMES=streets,points` should work without quotes. I would consider writing mail to gdal-dev list and ask if field name control of several layers is even supported.

Comment: @user30184 true, if you use the command line, `OGR_DISPLAY_LAYER_NAMES=streets,points` works without quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of a comment here (I wanted to include an image).
What about trying the following approach? Note casting the columns to a unique alias (i.e. stratt1 and stratt2 to 'sat', etc.):

[image: ogr.vrt changes]

```
OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD="sat"

OGR_DISPLAY_LAYER_NAMES="sat, inat"
```

Comment: That actually works! I´m giving you an upvote for your answer, because that trick might help others with the same question. I edited my question adding a picture of the output implementing your solution. Unfortunately this approach implies some beforehand preprocessing with GDAL which could be tricky to implement if someone has to achieve a standarized output (like in my case), but as long as the devs don't implement a better support for `OGR_DISPLAY_FIELD` this is definetly the way to go! Thanks! P.D: I´m going to need some time thorougly testing this approach, will keep updating!